# advice for table and query structure (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database-design

Here is my situation:

I have bloggers displaying on their blogs the last 10 posts. But they can subscribe to an other blog, so that the posts of the subscribed blog appears on the list of the posts on the subscriber blog (mixed with the owner posts). At this point I can manage.
But i'd like to allow the subscribers to remove some subscribed posts of their blog, the one they want, and the quantity they want.

The table of the posts is strucured like that:

id | user_id | title | post | date

How can I manage to allow the removal of some subscribed posts, without unsubscribe all the subscribed posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that typicllay, a blogger having subscribed to someone else's blog will only unsubscribe to a small number of posts, create a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `posts`. This relationship will the posts from which a user has explicitely unsubscribed.

When displaying the posts from the other blog, remove those posts the current user is related to via this relationship.

In the opposite case (if a user typically subscribe to a small number of posts from another blog), then model the subscription the opposite way: only link the user with those posts s/he has subscribed to.

Comment: In fact, by default the user subscribe to all posts of the other blog. And when he see it on their blog, he can decide to remove one or more, individualy. How can I structure my tables and query?